# Transferring File over TCP using Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am new to python and finding it really difficult trying to understand how to send files using sockets with a tcp connection
i found this code in another question that seems to be useful

Client Side

```
def _sendFile(self, path):
    sendfile = open(path, 'rb')
    data = sendfile.read()

    self._con.sendall(encode_length(len(data))) # Send the length as a fixed size message
    self._con.sendall(data)


    # Get Acknowledgement
    self._con.recv(1) # Just 1 byte
```

Server Side

```
def _recieveFile(self, path):
    LENGTH_SIZE = 4 # length is a 4 byte int.
    # Recieve the file from the client
    writefile = open(path, 'wb')
    length = decode_length(self.con.read(LENGTH_SIZE) # Read a fixed length integer, 2 or 4 bytes
    while (length):
        rec = self.con.recv(min(1024, length))
        writefile.write(rec)
        length -= sizeof(rec)

    self.con.send(b'A') # single character A to prevent issues with buffering
```

Now i have two problems with this code
First

```
self._con.sendall(encode_length(len(data)))
```

in this line it gives me an error saying encode_length is undefined

Secondly these are functions that send and receive file
Where do i call them 
Do i first form a TCP Connection and then call these functions
And how exactly to call them , if i call them directly it gives me an error on client side saying _sendFile(self, path) takes two arguments  (since i am not passing self just the path)

Thirdly i am using function from os library to get complete path , So i am calling the function like

```
_sendFile(os.path.abspath("file_1.txt"))
```

is this the correct way to pass the argument

Sorry i know this question is pretty basic and lame but everywhere online i can basically get the function but not how to call it

right now this is how i am calling the function

```
serverIP = '192.168.0.102'
serverPort = 21000

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

message = "Want to Backup a Directory"


clientSocket.connect((serverIP, serverPort))

_sendFile(os.path.abspath("file_1.txt"))
```

Which is basically wrong

I am using the same computer for both Client and Server

Running Python on Ubuntu using terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First problem:

It's because you simply haven't defined functions `encode/decode_lenght`.

---

## Second problem:

Your function is: `def _sendFile(self, path): ...`.
Do you know how to use `self`? It is used in the classes. So define it without `self`, or use classes:

### Example:

```
from socket import *
class Client(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    def connect(self, addr):

        self.clientSocket.connect(addr)

    def _sendFile(self, path):

        sendfile = open(path, 'rb')
        data = sendfile.read()

        self._con.sendall(encode_length(len(data))) # Send the length as a fixed size message
        self._con.sendall(data)


        # Get Acknowledgement
        self._con.recv(1) # Just 1 byte

>>> client = Client()
>>> client.connect(("192.168.0.102", 21000))
>>> client._sendFile(os.path.abspath("file_1.txt")) # If this file is in your current directory, you may just use "file_1.txt"
```

And same (almost) for `Server`.

---

Where to define these functions? In the code ofcorse! What should your functions do?
OK, an example:

```
def encode_length(l):

    #Make it 4 bytes long
    l = str(l)
    while len(l) < 4:
        l = "0"+l 
    return l

# Example of using
>>> encode_length(4)
'0004'
>>> encode_length(44)
'0044'
>>> encode_length(444)
'0444'
>>> encode_length(4444)
'4444'
```

---

### About self:

Just a little bit:

`self` redirects to your current object, ex:

```
class someclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 10
    def get(self):
        return self.var

>>> c = someclass()
>>> c.get()
10
>>> c.var = 20
>>> c.get()
20
>>> someclass.get(c)
20
>>>
```

How does `someclass.get(c)` work?
While executing `someclass.get(c)`, we **are not creating an new *instance*** of `someclass`.
When we call `.get()` from an `someclass` instance, it **automaticly** sets `self` to our instance object. So `someclass.get(c)` == `c.get()`
And if we try to do `someclass.get()`, `self` was **not** defined, so it will raise an error:
`TypeError: unbound method get() must be called with someclass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

---

You can use **decorator** to call functions of a class (not its instance!):

```
class someclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 10
    def get(self):
        return 10 # Raises an error
    @classmethod
    def get2(self):
        return 10 # Returns 10!
```

---

Sorry for my bad explanations, my English is not perfect

---

Here are some links:

[server.py](http://randomgalaxy.com/stackoverflow/transfering-file-over-tcp-using-python/server.py)

[client.py](http://randomgalaxy.com/stackoverflow/transfering-file-over-tcp-using-python/client.py)

Comment: what exactly is the definition of these functions , and any help with the rest , how do i call these functions and where ?

Comment: @user2557844, check out my modified answer

Comment: as i said i am really new to Python so really dont know how to use 
self
so basically i am suppose to create an object of class , call the connect function and pass the address and then call the send function
and when passing arguments i am not suppose to pass self , just the second argument and i should be done

Comment: @user2557844, yes something like this. `self` means your object class.

Comment: so basically self is similar to this in c++

Comment: @user2557844, I don't know how `this` acts in `c++`, but I think yes

Comment: user2557844, ooh. `self._con` is your socket client, right? So then you should do `self.clientSocket` instead of `self._con`! P.S. If you'd wait, I could write a simple example

Comment: that would be great  :)
and yes i figured out the con part , that was really dumb of me ,

Comment: @user2557844, check out my answer. I posted links there. And if you like the answer, please, accept it :)

Comment: getting this error

" rec = self.serverSocket.recv(1024)
socket.error: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
"

i am using port 22000

Comment: Thanks i will try out the code you wrote and get back , you have been of great help so far

Comment: You my friend are a legend , The code you sent works like a charm :)
Thank You , the hardwork you put in is much appreciated

Comment: @user2557844, no problem :) and if you want to understand more, read python docs :) http://docs.python.org/2/

Comment: Excellent! Also, note that the links of code are broken.