# how to send a large array over tcp socket in python? is it possible to send?

Tags: python

I don't have an example to show. I referred some online site, but didn't find anything that met my requirement. Please anyone give me an example to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, [so] is not a code writing service. You have to try something. [Help] has more information about the site policy and guidelines.

Comment: u first store the array in a file and send it over tcp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412029/transfering-file-over-tcp-using-python check this to send file

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options. I would try:

- instead of large array, try to get a generator or iterator which would provide items one by one. This could save you memory in sending process (but is is not necessary, if you can live with whole array in memory)
- do not use plain sockets, use ZeroMQ (which runs on top of it).
- define a protocol for sending the array. Assuming the array is flat, it can go with following types of messages:

  - startarray
  - itemdata
  - endarray
- loop over items to send and send them as one by one, before sending "startarray" message, then one item by one, finally closing by "endarray" message
- for transfer over TCP, you need to pick some serializatio format. I would start with JSON.
- sender could use ZMQ socket of type PUSH, receiver would be using PULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a minimum working example of how to achieve that in the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication).

For completeness, I have copied the code from the above mentioned site. You create a server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
     if not data: break
     print "received data:", data
     conn.send(data)  # echo
 conn.close()
```

And a client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print "received data:", data
```