# Can't pickle an RSA key to send over a socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, pickle

I have a list with a public key and a username that I want to send over a socket.

I found 
[how to send an array over a socket in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423162/how-to-send-an-array-over-a-socket-in-python) but using pickling won't work either.

My code:

```
private_key = generateRSA()
public_key = private_key.public_key()
host = ''
port = 8000
username = sys.argv[1]
mySocket = socket.socket()
mySocket.connect((host, port))
dataToSend = [public_key, username.encode()]
dataSend = pickle.dumps(dataToSend)
mySocket.send(dataSend)
```

The error in the console says

```
     dataSend = pickle.dumps(dataToSend)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_cffi_backend.CDataGCP'>: attribute lookup CDataGCP on _cffi_backend failed
```

The key was generated with the [`cryptography` library](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/).

Comment: Your question should be about why you can't pickle a CFFI object. The *reason* you are pickling is because you want to send an arbitrary object over a socket as data, but your problem lies with a specific type of object that can't easily be pickled.

Comment: Can you tell us what project provides the `generateRSA()` function? Then we can help you produce data for the private key; it is an object right now that can't easily be sent, not a string, for example.

Comment: That's the Python cryptography library. https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/

Comment: What are you planning to do with the data on the other side of the socket, @Amanda_Panda?  Do you actually need the public key *object*, or just a string representation?

Comment: The public key is needed for encryption. I guess I don't really need the object per se then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send a [`RSAPublicKey` instance](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicKey), but this is a data structure managed by SSL, not Python. Because you interact with it through a CFFI proxy, you can't pickle one of these.

You'll need to pick a [*key serialization format*](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#key-serialization) to send it instead. You could convert to PEM, for example:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
pem = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)
```

The above would export your key to a string value you could then convert to bytes and send over the socket directly. The other side would [load the key](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#key-loading) from that string again.

Note that the above uses **no encryption whatsoever**. Anyone intercepting the traffic over that socket would be able to read your public key. That may or may not be a problem for your application.

Comment: It looks like the PEM version of the public key is what I want to send. Not the private key!

Comment: @Amanda_Panda: ah, you linked to the RSA *Private* key interface, which threw me. I'll update.

Comment: @Amanda_Panda: updated to use the `public_bytes()` method to serialise to the most common PEM format.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I forgot about serialization and the PEM format.